# Replace question mark with respective parameter string

Tags: java, replace, java-8

I have a sql query like below and I want to replace the question mark with respective binded parameters passed. How will I construct this String

`select this_.id, this_.name from table this_ where this_.depId = ? and this_.perStatus = ?`

I want to replace the question mark like below

`select this_.id, this_.name from table this_ where this_.depId = 10 and this_.perStatus = 'Active'`

How do I replace all the question marks with respective parameters.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: it looks like you want to use Prepared Statements. I recommend reading a good tutorial about that: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Will you execute that query on an actual database? Then use actual prepared statements.

Comment: Use the JDBC features for binding parameter values. Do *not* modify the SQL statement text.

Comment: I am not going to execute this query. I just want to manipulate and construct the query for some debug tool purpose. I will be getting the sql string for any CRUD or proc/func call with question mark when I enable to show_sql true with hibernate config. I just want to manipulate the binded parameters alone with sql for logging purpose.

Comment: In which form are the values `10` and `'Active'` given?

Comment: @Holger This will be in a map and I need to manipulate and place it at the correct placeholder. I am not going to execute this query.

Comment: I understand that this is only for reporting. But the only thing distinguishing the question marks, is their relative position. So if the actual values are in a map, do you actually want to replace the pattern “name = ?” with “name = ” plus the result of looking up “name” in the map?

Comment: Yes, that is what I needed. I have just shared a select statement. It can be procedure call or insert/delete statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we agree that this should never be used to construct a `Statement` but only for debugging messages, you can do it like

```java
static final Pattern COMPARISON = Pattern.compile("((\\w+)\\s*[<>=]+\\s*)\\?");

static String debugExpression(String actualQuery, Map<String,Object> values) {
    return COMPARISON.matcher(actualQuery)
        .replaceAll(mr -> mr.group(1) + forValue(values.get(mr.group(2))));
}

private static String forValue(Object o) {
    return o instanceof Number || o instanceof Boolean? o.toString():
        o == null? " *** key not in map ***":
        "'" + Matcher.quoteReplacement(o.toString()) + "'";
}
```

This searches for occurrences of “name  comparison operator  question mark” and replaces the question mark with a representation of the value found in the map for “name”.

If you prefer to enforce the “name” to be prepended by `this_.` you can use the  following pattern instead:

```java
static final Pattern COMPARISON
    = Pattern.compile("(?<=this_\\.)((\\w+)\\s*[<>=]+\\s*)\\?");
```

If we test it with

```java
String query = "select this_.id, this_.name from table this_ where this_.depId = ? and this_.perStatus = ?";
System.out.println(debugExpression(query, Map.of("depId", 10, "perStatus", "Active")));
```

It will print

```
select this_.id, this_.name from table this_ where this_.depId = 10 and this_.perStatus = 'Active'
```

This will not replace other question marks, like the `(?, ? …)` of an update or insert statement, as there’s no context to derive the right key from.

---

The code above uses Java 9 features. If you need Java 8 compatibility, the replacement logic needs to be implemented manually:

```
static String debugExpression(String actualQuery, Map<String,Object> values) {

  Matcher m = COMPARISON.matcher(actualQuery);
  if(!m.find()) return actualQuery;

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(actualQuery.length() + 100);
  int start = 0;

  do {
    sb.append(actualQuery, start, m.end(1));
    start = m.end();
    Object o = values.get(m.group(2));

    if(o == null) sb.append(" *** key not in map ***");
    else if(o instanceof Number || o instanceof Boolean) sb.append(o);
    else sb.append("'").append(o).append("'");

  } while(m.find());

  return sb.append(actualQuery, start, actualQuery.length()).toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Let me give a try on this. I use java 8 and there can be a procedure or function calls too. I will try and let you know.

Comment: I could use part of your code to get the data without the column name. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Java and I am not a Java-expert so hope this answer can help you a bit.

#### Normal way (Vulnerable to injection attack)

```
String depId = "10";
String perStatus = "'Active'";

String query = "select this_.id, this_.name from table this_ where 
this_.depId = %s and this_.perStatus = %s";
String finalQuery = String.format(query, depId, perStatus);

System.out.println(finalQuery);
```

#### Safeway (PreparedStatement)

```
String query = "select this_.id, this_.name from table this_ where this_.depId = ? and this_.perStatus = ?";
PreparedStatement prepStatQuery = con.prepareStatement(query);

prepStatQuery.setInt(1, 10);
prepStatQuery.setString(2, "Active");

ResultSet resSet = prepStatQuery.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many options here:

1. Use `String.format` [method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-string-format-method-with-examples/) and align the parameters in the order you want. Here you will replace your **?** with a format specifier.
2. With JDBC you have to [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).
3. Or with Spring Data check this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Stored Procedures in you're Case.
They are easy to create and are stored on you're Database directly.
You're Stored Procedure could look like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE yourProcedureName
    @depId int,
    @perStatus varchar(10),
    AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT this_.id, this_.name from table this_ where this_.depId = @depId and this_.perStatus = @perStatus
END
```

Here is some example how you could call your Stored Procedure in your Java Code.

```
public void storedProcedure(Int depId, String perStatus, String connectionUrl){
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pStatement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        // Establish the connection
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

        // Prepare the stored procedure call
        String storedProcedure = "{CALL procedureName(?,?)}";
        pStatement = connection.prepareCall(storedProcedure);

        pStatement.setInt(1,depId);
        pStatement.setString(2,perStatus);


        pStatement.execute();

        pStatement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if(rs != null) try {
            rs.close();
        }catch (Exception e){}
        if(pStatement!=null) try {
            pStatement.close();
        }catch (Exception e){}
        if(con!=null) try{con.close();} catch (Exception e){}
    }

}
```